# PostgreSQL (ef core), bulk deleting / reinserting a table with 1.5 million rows gets slower each run

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, bulkinsert

I have a small PostgreSQL table 1.5 million rows `(uuid id, integer productId, integer rankType, text rankKey, integer position)`, no indexes except PK, every 10 minutes I need to empty/regenerate the entire table based on a few calculations in code, product ids vary so this is a delete/insert, not update. Other code might query the existing table while it's regenerating so I never want the table to be empty or locked ideally.

I'm using EF Core + the EFCore.BulkExtensions for bulk insert which uses `COPY BINARY` under the hood. Anyway I have code that achieves exactly what I want to do, no downtime, etc:

```
using (var transaction = _ctx.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
   await _ctx.ProductRanks.ExecuteDeleteAsync();
   await _ctx.BulkInsertAsync(allRanks);
   transaction.Commit();
}
```

...but it gets slower each run, first run 5 seconds, then 10, 15, 20 which is no good.

If I truncate the table instead of bulk deleting the records:

```
using (var transaction = _ctx.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
   await _ctx.TruncateAsync<ProductRank>();
   await _ctx.BulkInsertAsync(allRanks);
   transaction.Commit();
}
```

...it remains a consistent 5 seconds each execution, but then the table is locked in the as it's reinserting the records which isn't ideal.

Instead, going back to the first code, if I manually `VACCUM` the table after the inserts:

```
using (var transaction = _ctx.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
   await _ctx.ProductRanks.ExecuteDeleteAsync();
   await _ctx.BulkInsertAsync(allRanks);
   transaction.Commit();
}
_ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("VACUUM(FULL) product_ranks");
```

It remains a consistent 7 seconds per run... but again this locks the table while doing the full vacuum. It seems like this is something PostgreSQL should be handling itself. I'm wondering if I'm missing something that would make it work without doing this?

autovacuum is enabled, but the quick vacuum performed by autovacuum
doesn't fix the slowdown, only a full vacuum does.

If I check the vacuum log:

```
SELECT last_autovacuum , last_autoanalyze, relname FROM pg_stat_user_tables;
```

It *is* running a vacuum on the table, but doesn't actually make the inserts faster until I manually run a full vacuum as in the query above.

Comment: Did you try a manual VACUUM without the FULL and between each one, and observe that it didn't fix the problem?  Or are you just assuming it won't since autovac didn't?  You could probably regenerate your table many times in the time it takes autovac to start and then finish, so just letting autovac do its things is not at all the same as using an enforced cadence with the manual non-FULL vacuum.

Comment: Since you are completely replacing the table's contents on each cycle perhaps you could: 1 create a stage table. 2. Load the new data to the stage. 3 Drop the table. 4 Rename the stage table. That sequence should only create waits as step 3. You will, however, have to deal with *table does not exist* exception for the time span between 3 and  4, short though it may be. Downside: Test, Test, Test required.

Comment: If you can change your read code to read from a view you could use @Belayer's approach slightly modified. Keep 2 tables and alternate the one you truncate/insert, once the refresh is done you change the view to point to the most recent table.

Comment: @jjanes, Belayer, Victor Ortuondo Thanks for your replies. I misunderstood vacuum, it seems as I was testing I never actually ran a full vacuum and then quick vacuum. If I do as jjanes said and run a full vacuum (once) and then use the code as per example #3 but with a quick not full vacuum it stays consistently fast and without table locking. I'll still look into views/temp tables though! thanks again